# mp4, webm, ogg video files not playing when called from webserver

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, mp4, ogg, webm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.tb_bg {
background-image: url(../images/audi/audi_land.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
   }
   .vid_pos{
position:static;
   }
   #apDiv1 {
position:absolute;
width:255px;
height:163px;
z-index:1;
left: 69px;
top: 478px;
   }
 -->
 </style>
 </head>

  <body>
 <div id="apDiv1" class="vid_pos">
 <video width="350" height="220" preload="meta" controls="controls"      poster="../images/audi/audi_poster.png">

 <source src="../videos/audi/audi.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />

 <source src="../videos/audi/audi.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />

 <source src="../videos/audi/audi.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />

  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width: 300px; height: 170px;" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf?flv=/videos/audi/dell_audi.mp4&amp;amp;autoplay=false">

 <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />

  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />

  </object>
  </video>

   </div>
    <table width="800" height="1005" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"              class="tb_bg">
     <tr>
      <td height="1003">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      </table>

      </body>
      </html>
```

There is no error in the coding. When I open above file in all 3 browsers Chrome, IE & Firefox, the video plays. but after I upload the video files and html files to the server and call the page, the video does not play on Firefox and IE. It works on Google Chrome..

There is no PHP or Apache involved in this...

The server space is from www.godaddy.com..

When I open the file in Firefox : I get the following message where I have placed the video file :***"No video with supported format and MIME type found"***

and on IE
I only see the image -audi_poster.png

What should I do now? The video plays when I open from my local drives in ALL 3 browsers.. I don't why it doesn't work when I upload to server and call it..
Any additional stuff needed?? Pls help..

Answer (score 4):

Your web server must respond to the browser with a correct Content-Type header. For WebM, 'video/webm'. More [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#video-mime-types).